# Where in my Rails app do classes responsible for doing 3rd party API calls go?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, code-organization, project-organization

My application interfaces with a number of internal APIs in order to periodically import data and I was wondering where the appropriate place to put this code lives.

Some common places i've seen are `/app/models/third_party_api.rb` OR `/lib/apis/third_party_api.rb` but i have no idea what the common convention is.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can place that code at many places. `app/models`, `app/api_clients/<api_name>`, `lib/api_clients/<api_name>`

Or probably the best is to create a gem for each api wich you can use in your Gemfile, and if you don't want to publish them you can just place it at `vendor/gems/<gem_name>` and use it with

```
gem 'gem_name', path: 'vendor/gems/gem_name'
```

And you have your api client separated from the rest of the project, with it's own test suite and easy to reuse later on other projects. I took this approach in a recent project and I'm very happy with it.